# Sort results from an Index based on another index

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I have some data with relating fields; Here is a relating example to what I have in my index

**user index**

```
[
   {
      "id": "user_1",
      "name": "xxx",
   },
   {
      "id": "user_2",
      "name": "xxx",
   },
   {
      "id": "user_3",
      "name": "xxx",
   },
   {
      "id": "user_4",
      "name": "xxx",
   }
]
```

**posts index**

```
[
   {
      "id": "post_1",
      "title": "xxx",
      "user_id": "user_1",
      "created": "10-2-2022"
   },
   {
      "id": "post_2",
      "title": "xxx",
      "user_id": "user_3",
      "created": "11-2-2022"
   },
   {
      "id": "post_3",
      "title": "xxx",
      "user_id": "user_1",
      "created": "9-2-2022"
   }
]
```

I want to sort `users` based on the posts `created` date.

##### The result I want for `desc`

```
[
   {
      "id": "user_3"   # Given that they have to most recent post `post_2`
   },
   {
      "id": "user_1"
   },
   {
      "id": "user_2"
   },
   {
      "id": "user_4"
   }
]
```

**Note:** That `user_2` & `user_4` has 0 posts, but was added at the end of the result.

Any ideas on how to implement this optimally?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in elastic search.

Elastic search does not have concept of join. You will need to de-normalize your data. Bring   all data together. You can explore [parent/child](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/parent-join.html) or [nested fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) for this.